Babel won't transpile export statement of my .js file
Let's suppose I have following trying.js file:
import {BaseException} from "../public/libs/pdfjs/build/pdf";

let __webpack_exports__ = globalThis.pdfjsLib = {};

class AbortException extends BaseException {
  constructor(msg) {
    super(msg, "AbortException");
  }
}

let __webpack_exports__AbortException = __webpack_exports__.AbortException;

export { __webpack_exports__AbortException as AbortException }

I have following .babelrc file:
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}

I have following babel.config.js file:
const presets = [
    [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
            "modules": "commonjs",
            targets: {
                edge: "17",
                firefox: "60",
                chrome: "67",
                safari: "11.1",
            },
            useBuiltIns: "usage",
            corejs: "3.6.4",
        },
    ],
];

module.exports = { presets };

I have following package.json file:
...
"browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.25.7",
    "@babel/core": "^7.25.7",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining": "^7.25.7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object": "^7.25.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.25.7"
  },

The problem: When I try to transpile the code like this:
npx babel ./src/trying.js --out-dir ./
My last line
export { __webpack_exports__AbortException as AbortException }

won't get transpiled.
Do you know why?
Please help me, as I'm stuck on this problem. I tried to run
npx babel ./src/trying.js --out-dir ./

but my export line won't get transpiled.
I have to manually insert the code so that it compiles correctly.
This is part of a larger project, and I don't want to manually insert the
export { __webpack_exports__AbortException as AbortException }

everytime I compile the react.js project.
Let me know if you need something else.
[EDIT]: This line won't get transpiled. I added a picture.

Thanks
